# How to pass an error message occuring inside the FOR /F loop body into the FOR parameter in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if I can capture error messages directly (just like an output from a successfully executed command would be) and do whatever I want with it, such as storing it in a variable, or passing it as a parameter.

Here's what I'm trying to do lately. Please check the code:

```bat
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%s IN (
    'WMIC DISKDRIVE WHERE SerialNumber^="sn999" GET SerialNumber /VALUE'
) DO (
    IF "%%s"=="sn999" (GOTO Label1) ELSE (GOTO Label2)
)
```

What I'm trying to do here is to check if a particular external hard drive is plugged-in by comparing the serial number, and from then, the code will determine which path to take. It works as intended if the desired external hard drive is plugged-in. However, if the external hard drive with the same serial number is not plugged-in, I get the following message:

*No Instance(s) Available.*

And as a consequence I get these issues:

- ELSE clause would not push through
- The code didn't raise the ERRORLEVEL. So, I can't use this either as a workaround.

My research led me to these sources:

[Redirecting Error Messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout)

[Display & Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)

Both links discuss redirecting error messages. I thought I can just write few lines of code to redirect error messages to a text file, recover it and parse the contents, and finally clean it up. But I'm not sure if this is the best idea though. So, I'd appreciate any suggestion that you may have that may work with the code above. Also, I'd like to know why %ERRORLEVEL% is 0 even though I got an error message. Lastly, I'd like to know if it is possible to capture error messages without writing anything to the hard drive.

Thank you all very much!!

Comment: If you use `findstr` you can use errorlevel. Something like `(WMIC DISKDRIVE ^| findstr /i /C:"sn999") if %errorlevel%==0 echo drive found`

Comment: Great idea. I never thought about this. I'm too focused on the idea of storing it in a variable and use it to compare against the serial number. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I added an answer with the correct method. The comment was a guess.

Comment: When I saw your first comment about FINDSTR, I saw the whole idea already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `findstr` makes you able to use `errorlevel`.

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('WMIC DISKDRIVE ^| findstr /I /C:"sn999"') do if %errorlevel%==0 echo Drive Found & goto :EOF
echo Drive not Found.
```

This basically does a search on the string and if found sets `errorlevel` to `0`, if not found `errorlevel` will be `1`.

If `errorlevel` is `0` then it will `echo` **Drive Found** and `goto :EOF` if `errorlevel` is not 1, it skips the line as the condition was not met and it will `echo` **Drive not Found**.

If you still want to use the labels, then simply do:

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('WMIC DISKDRIVE ^| findstr /I /C:"sn999"') do if %errorlevel%==0 goto :label1

REM This will act as label2
echo Drive not found
goto :EOF

:label1
echo Drive found
goto :EOF
```

Note we do not have to use `goto label2` as it will automatically go passed the errorlevel match and continue, only label1 is really needed then.

Comment: This will do. Thank you very much, Gerhard. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Marked it already. Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I can't upvote yet because I just recently joined the network. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Put `GOTO Label2` after the loop. If `GOTO Label1` is triggered, then the `GOTO Label2` will be avoided as it will jump to the label.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%s IN (
    'WMIC DISKDRIVE WHERE SerialNumber^="sn999" GET SerialNumber /VALUE'
) DO (
    IF "%%~s"=="sn999" GOTO Label1
)
GOTO Label2
```

You could also suppress the stderr message of `No Instance(s) Available.` with `2^>nul` if you prefer.

Comment: That's a clever idea, man. I like it. Who would've thought that re-arranging the code could make a big difference? Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to use a `For` loop in this instance because a metavariable is not required.
*The `For` loop runs the `WMIC` command in another instance of `cmd.exe` unnecessarily.*

```bat
@Echo Off
WMIC DiskDrive Where SerialNumber="sn999" List Instance 2>Nul|Find "I">Nul && GoTo :Label1
Echo Drive Not Found & Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Label1
Echo Drive Found & Pause
GoTo :EOF
```